# PHP Login script receive blank screen in Hostinger

Tags: php, authentication, database-connection

I have a confusing problem in login form, it seems work well when i try it in localhost but it gives a blank white screen when i upload it to hostinger. I think its not about the database connection. Please help me, because it doesn't give me an error reporting. Here's php code, the form and inputs name does match.

```
<?
$host = "localhost";
$user = "HIDDEN";
$pass = "HIDDEN";
$db   = "connect_11265";
$koneksi=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die ("koneksi ke database gagal") ;
$koneksi_database= mysql_select_db($db,$koneksi);
if(ISSET($_POST['username'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $cek = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($cek)==1){//jika berhasil akan bernilai 1
        $c = mysql_fetch_array($cek);
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $c['username'];
        $_SESSION['level'] = $c['level'];
        if($c['level']=="administrator"){
            header('location:admin/index.php?page=dashboard');
        }elseif($c['level']="operator"){
            header('location:admin/index.php?page=dashboard');
        }
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: what is the url you are seeing on the blank page?

Comment: if else condition is meaning-less as you are redirect to the same page in both case :)

Answer (score 1):

I Assume, in `hostinger` not enabled the shortag options `<? ?>`, Can you try using `<?php ?>`.

BTW,

```
  elseif($c['level']=="operator")
                .....^
```

instead of

```
 elseif($c['level']="operator")
```

Comment: btw that if else condition is meaning-less as he is redirect to the same page in both case :)

Answer (score 0):

Header is not working on Hostinger .... 
Localhost for a mysql server is mysql.hostinger.hu